# Inverted Interval Frequency Relationship

Tags: theory, intervals

I’ve been recently interested in the idea of ‘pull’ in music. I’m almost certain this this set of ideas is not new in any way, but I’ve found it hard to find good material for this.

I’m interested in understanding if the ‘pull’ of an interval corresponds to the same ‘pull’ of the inverted interval. I compared some known interval ratios and the ratios match up as,

X—>X’ => l:m —> 2m:l

where X is the initial interval and X’ is the inverted interval.

My question really is, why does that 2 show up? And do you guys think that a ratio of and interval has the same ‘pull’ as the inverted interval (in the context of the ‘opposite harmony’ I guess we can call it.)

Answer (score 3):

> why does that 2 show up?

It is the definition of inversion.  From Wikipedia's [article on inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(music)):

> An interval is inverted by raising or lowering either of the notes by one or more octaves.

From Wikipedia's [article on the octave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octave):

> an octave ... is the interval between one musical pitch and another with double its frequency.

Here's an example.  Suppose your interval is the ascending major third, the ratio being 5:4, and your lower pitch is A=440 Hz.  The higher pitch is therefore 550 Hz.  To raise the lower frequency by an octave, you multiply it by 2 to get 880 Hz.  This is now the higher frequency, of course, so the ratio of the ascending minor sixth (from C♯=550 Hz to A=880 Hz in this example) is 8:5.

If you invert the ratio of an interval without multiplying by 2, you change its direction without changing its identity.  In the example, we used the ratio 5:4 to calculate a frequency for C♯ from A=440 Hz; the inverted ratio 4:5 allows us to calculate a frequency for F from A=440 Hz (yielding 352 Hz).  Thus the mathematical concept of multiplicative inversion is not directly applicable to the musical concept of interval inversion.

Answer (score 2):

An interval X combined with its inversion X' always forms an octave, which is a 2:1 ratio. That's where the 2 comes from in the expression in question.

As a general rule, intervals and their inversions are treated similarly, but pulling in opposite directions. For example, an augmented fourth is expected to resolve to a sixth, but a diminished fifth (the inversion of an augmented fourth) is expected to resolve to a third (the inversion of a sixth).

Answer (score 0):

With one exception, intervals have approximately the same "dissonance" or "pull"; as pointed out in other answers, this may be in the "opposite" direction.

There is at least one anomaly. The perfect fourth (the inversion of the perfect fifth) is treated as a dissonance against the current bass note but can be treated as a consonance if against a higher note.

C-E-G consists of 3 consonant intervals, C-E (M3), E-G (m3), C-G (P5).
E-G-C consists of 3 consonant intervals, E-G (m3), G-C (P4), E-C (m6).
G-C-E consists of 1 dissonant and 2 consonant intervals, G-C (P4), C-E (M3), G-E (M6). (And I hope that I computed the qualities of the intervals.)

There is another "pull" happening here that is not based just on interval sizes. Augmented intervals are "pulled" (tend to be resolved) outward whilst diminished intervals tend to be resolved inward. F-B is an augmented fourth and resolves outward to E-G; the inversion (also a tritone) B-F is a diminished fifth and resolves inward to C-E.

Comment: I don't understand the tritone concept. F-B is aug4, but the same sounding F-Cb is dim5. So why would one resolve inwards, but exactly (in 12tet) the same sounding other have to resolve outwards? And vice versa. Help!

Comment: The augmented fourth is not equal to the diminished fifth musically. These intervals become the same for pianos (and other keyboards) and for some fretted string instruments (lute, guitar, etc.). Singers and violin family players will adjust to something similar to "just" tuning. Musical notation is written with singers in mind, not pianists.